# Generate a new JUnit test after implementing some methods of a class under test

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I am newbie in IntelliJ, I used to use NetBeans. My situation is the following:

1. I create the class and the corresponded test.
2. I create some method in the class.

Is there is any feature in IntelliJ for refactoring the test, so that the new method/function created will generate its corresponding test function in the test class? I stress that the test file is already generated.

**Edit1:** My aim is updating the current test, not generating a new one. I am looking to a feature which implements the new test function into the current test. Here is the situation with snippet code:

`src/pack/Foo.java`

```
package pack

class Foo {
     \\ variables
     public Foo (arguments){
         \\ variable initialization
     }

     private void metho1(){ ... }
```

- I generate the test.

`Test/pack/FooTest.groovy`

```
package pack

class FooTest {
     private static Foo tmp = new Foo (arguments)

     void testmetho1(){ ... }
```

- So now I create several methods into `Foo.java`.

`src/pack/Foo.java`

```
package pack

class Foo {
     \\ variables
     public Foo (arguments){
         \\ variable initialization
     }

     private void metho1(){ ... }
     private void metho2(){ ... }
     private void metho3(){ ... }
```

- What I want is to update the `FooTest.groovy` in such a way that`metho2, metho3` created in `Foo.java` will generate the functions tests for them.

`Test/pack/FooTest.groovy`

```
package pack

class FooTest {
     private static Foo tmp = new Foo (arguments)

     void testmetho1(){ ... }
     void testmetho1(){ ... }
     void testmetho1(){ ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put my cursor on the new method name

press {Generate... (default Alt+Insert I think)}

Select 'Tests...'

select my method(s) I want to generate test scaffolding for

have it use the existing class.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-tests.html):

**Create test methods**

To create stub test methods in JUnit test classes, you can use the IntelliJ IDEA code generation feature.

1. Open the corresponding JUnit test class in the editor.
2. Place the cursor where you want a new test method to be generated.
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and select **Test Method** from the **Generate** menu.